# configuration for my wireless connection

Tags: networking, drivers, wifi

I had connection issues so I changed some wireless configuration.
I think I solved the problem, but I still have minor issues.
First thing I had my Internet connection freeze badly,
Then after doing those configuration things changed,

```
modprobe rtl8187 &&
iwconfig wlan0 rate 5.5M auto fixed &&
iwconfig wlan0 rts auto &&
iwconfig wlan0 frag auto
```

It's now more stable and faster,
 but my wireless connection still freeze(I only notice that while gaming) like
1-3 seconds every while(range from minutes to hours).
And I'm sure it's not my Internet, so I think it's my configuration..

Note:
Device: Alfa 036H
Driver: RTL8187L

Did someone experience this before?
What are the right configuration for my device/driver?
and what does rts, frag and rate means?
I might be able to fix it myself, if I can understand them.

Comment: Try to install `wicd`, for me it resolved a lot of wireless issues, it has a gui too `wicd-gtk`.

Comment: As much as I hate to say it, you should not jump to conclusions about what the problem is until you have done a thorough analysis with `ping` and `mtr`.  Find out at which hop in the path you're loosing packets.  Then, come back and let us know whether it was your wireless or something upstream of it.  That said, wifi is a terrible technology from a reliability perspective... if you suspect wireless and you're not sure how to do the above, just take an ethernet cable and plug it into the back of your wifi router (must have RJ45 ethernet jacks).  Be sure both sides support dhcp